# How to export TRPC router type to other project

Tags: next.js, routes, vite, trpc

I have a project in typescript using the next.js framework, I also have trpc/server, I’m also creating a project in vite.js and I want to use the trpc router type, that is, appRouter.

I can't pass the router type to declare trpc/client using the appRouter router type. Can you help?

I tried to import directly but the type is converted to any

Answer (score 0):

Export router type:

```
const appRouter = ...;
export type AppRouter = typeof appRouter;
```

Then you need to build a .d.ts file and publish it. E.g., if the name of your TypeScript file is index.ts, then run

```bash
npx tsc --declaration --outDir dist
```

It will generate two files: index.js and index.d.ts in dist folder.

Then you can publish the dist folder on npm (publicly or privately). Make sure to include `"types": "./dist/index.d.ts"` in package.json.

Then, you can install the package in your client project and import `AppRouter` from it.

I would also advise you NOT to publish index.js file because you probably don't want to publish your server source code to npm. You would need to remove index.js from dist folder manually or automatically before publishing. Or you can use vite on server to only emit index.d.ts file. You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-dts to bundle .d.ts files using vite.